# How to join dataset iteratively in Pig?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I wish to join a data set (parent-child) multiple time with itself to flatten a hierarchical model. I already know the maximum depth of the hierarchy. To flatten such a data set I had to join this data iteratively. How can this be done in Pig any clue?

Example:
Sample Tree:

```
A
|--B--D
|     
|--C--E
   |--F
   |--G
```

Storage:

```
Child|Parent
D|B
B|A
C|A
E|C
F|C
G|C
```

Required Output

```
Node | Path
D    | A/B/D
E    | A/C/E
F    | A/C/F
G    | A/C/G
D    | A/B/D
```

This is just a sample data set and tree can be of any predefined max level and any structure.

Comment: Could you provide an example of you data and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: updated above question with details.